# Anaconda 3 installation error - no scripts folder and no conda command prompt and shortcuts

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to install Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64.exe on window 8.1. During installation, I checked details and there seemed have many issues.

- No Scripts folder or Conda Command prompt or shortcuts were created.
- Only conda-meta, Lib, pkgs,_conda.exe and Uninstall-Anaconda3.exe are created.

I tried 32 bits also and miniconda versions. All of them don't work for me. I already tried multiple uninstallation and installation. But the result is the same.

any inputs will be very helpful.

> Extract: anaconda-2019.10-py37_0.tar.bz2 [7424] Failed to execute
>   script conda.exe
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 149,
>   in **init**   File "ctypes__init__.py", line 348, in **init**
>   OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "conda.exe.py", line 45, in
>
> File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line
>   151, in **init**
>   **main**.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 'C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI77242\archive.dll'.
>   Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was
>   frozen.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 149,
>   in **init**   File "ctypes__init__.py", line 348, in **init**
>   OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Comment: Looks like your installer might be corrupted.  Try downloading a new copy and install as admin.

Comment: Error log similar to this,
https://superuser.com/questions/1473878/anaconda-fails-to-install-fully-on-windows-7-solved-bad-hard-drive
Please check.

Comment: Hi @James, I even checked MD5 hash value for the downloaded file and it is correct.  So download was fine.

Comment: @SauravJoshi, yes. I already checked that. it was kinda of similar. but my harddisk is fine and the problem was I couldn't see any of the folder or shortcuts or conda prompt. so it is impossible for me to proceed what it was suggested in answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I used 64 bit preview version of installer from from [2020 Feb](https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/misc/previews/anaconda/2020.02/). The installation was completed successfully now and everything is working fine. I suspect there is issue with 2019.10 verion which might have caused problems.

Thanks to the [github conda issues page](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues) which leads to this solution.

Make sure to check [hash values of your installer](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/) just for in case too.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it's the opposite. When i used the installers from 2020, Anaconda is installed in `C:\Users\username\Anaconda3`. This gives me the same problem as you with no Scripts folder, no command prompt, no Anaconda Navigator. I tried the 2019 version and now Anaconda is installed in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3` and it works.

Maybe changing the install path for the 2020 versions would have worked too. I didnt try it though. I have Windows 10 and used the x86_64 files.

Comment: I have the same problem with the 2020 distribution, did you solve it?

Comment: hey there, yeah as mentioned i used a 2019 version.

Comment: i have too same problem, it worked thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be eradicated by uninstalling the current version of `conda` and install the previous version of anaconda [anaconda 2019.03](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.03-Windows-x86_64.exe). It will help solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This problem still exists in  Anaconda3 2021.11. I suspect the problem is in the username (might be that this occurs only with certain localizations). If the username has special characters or space the AppData/Local/Continuum folder will simply be missing. What is unacceptable is the installer telling the installation was a success.

If you install it globally you will still not be able to use it when you create a new enviroment (It tries to put it in the user folder, succeeds, then doesn't find anything when eg. you try to install new packages to this env). (This might be dependent on other localization settings too)

Solution is to create a simple user folder like instead of Kovács Xaviér make it KovacsXavier (I'm sure the Caps doesn't bother it). Now you will be able to install it.

If you have a new windows installation you can trick windows into creating such a short username by adding this as your "UserName" first and later renaming yourself. The directory created will remain the same but you can rename your displayed name later. I really doesn't recommend anyone letting Windows create a fancy named home folder. Not anaconda is the only software that has problems with this.

Another notable observation that you better leash your antivirus software when installing Anaconda.

But it is obvious Anaconda doesn't check software integrity after install. Which is sad.

Answer (score 0):

Global search for the file .condarc in the drive you installed in. Uninstall anaconda and delete .condarc file. Reinstall Anaconda and you should be good to go. Was stuck with this problem for hours, hope this helps!